# Simulating ARFIMA data

Tags: data

In R, can you simulate a stationary ARFIMA process by using the "arfima.sim" function in the "nsarfima" package by specifying the d parameter to be between 0 and 0.5? If you do this, will the data still be simulated as "non covariance stationary"?